# Apache Tomcat refrencing to JDK which is not installed and not refrence in classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat6

I am trying to start my Apache tomcat server in Eclipse.
But every time I get the error

> The archive: C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_20/lib/tools.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.

I have installed JDK jdk1.7.0_60 and same is been mentioned in path variable in Environmental variable.
Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Is that where it is installed?

Comment: i have installed jdk 7 and not jdk 6 but i get this error whenever i try to start tomcat server in eclipse

Comment: The path is pointing to `/jdk1.6.0_20` just change the path to point to 1.7

Comment: Which Tomcat server version are you using? And did you configure java in Eclipse ? Window -> Preferences ->Java ->Installed JRE's.

Comment: @Chris Bolton how to change it to 1.7 coz path variable is pointing to jdk1.7

Comment: @KalyanChavali I am using tomcat 6 and installed JRE is JRE 7

Comment: ok. Just add your Java 1.7 to eclipse Window -> Preferences ->Java ->Installed JRE's and select (check box) this version of Java and run your tomcat.

Comment: @KalyanChavali There is only JRE7 available in Installed JRE and it is been selected. Nothing else is available there.

Comment: You would need to add the JDK that you have installed. Installed JRE's -> Add - > Standard VM -> Browse yous installation of JDK7 and click Apply. Then select this JD7 to be used by eclipse.

Comment: @KalyanChavali Thank you dude. You have solved my problem. Server is now started. Thanks a Lot.